# Arbor/JQuery DOM Exception 18

Tags: jquery, arbor.js

I'm drawing connections graph using arbor.js and raphael.js. On my localhost everything work ok, but on heroku, i get following error:

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 arbor.js:33
j.init                arbor.js:33
Kernel                arbor.js:33
ParticleSystem        arbor.js:35
(anonymous function)  pg.js:63
f                     jquery.min.js:1
p.fireWith            jquery.min.js:1
st.extend.ready       jquery.min.js:1
xt                    jquery.min.js:1
```

In my code (pg.js) it comes up on `arbor.ParticleSystem()`. All my static files come from amazon s3, and latest jquery comes from google ajax libs.

I searched the web for the last 3 days trying to find what causes it. I don't use any file:// and I don't use canvas.

What causes this error? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the lines `window.location.protocol=="file:"&&` at the beginning of the kernel.js function in the arbor.js source and it seems to work.

Still not sure what the real problem with that is though...